# Differentiate users in google analytics

Tags: google-analytics

Want to differentiate users in google analytics.My website is for online course where different type of users can login   such as parents,students,instructors,admin.I want to report that how many different users logged in?

Answer (score 1):

Create a custom dimension, via property settings/custom definitions/custom dimensions.

Dimensions come in different scopes, hit level scope (pertaining to pageviews and events etc), session level scope (referring to a visit, in this case setting the value once per session will be enough) or user scopes (pertaining to multiple recurring visits; use only if you do not expect the value to change after is has been set).

Depending on your reporting needs you should at least create a session scoped custom dimension, and maybe a hit level scoped one ( a session contains pageviews before the login; the session scoped variable will, AFAIK, be applied to all pageviews in the session even  before login).

While the dimension will have a name in the tracking code it is referred to by the prefix "dimension" followed by an numeric index. For the first custom dimension you created the tracking code will look something like

```
ga('create', 'UA-XXXX-Y', 'auto');
// Set value for custom dimension at index 1.
ga('set', 'dimension1', '[status]');
// Send the custom dimension value with a pageview hit.
ga('send', 'pageview');
```

where `[status]` is a placeholder that needs to be replaced with the fitting value (i.e. parent, student etc.). You need to set the dimension before a pageview (or event etc.) since custom dimensions are only transferred along with an interaction hit.

Custom dimensions do not show up in the standard reports by default - you can use them in segmentation, set them as secondary dimension, or create custom reports based on your dimensions.

Comment: Thanks @Eike Pierstorff.After add this code to javascript?How to set custom dimension in google analytics?How come it knows that I signed In with student or parent?